# User Management for Android

Tags: android, networking, backend, elgg, whatsapp

We're developing an app which locates a person in our college campus via wifi localisation. However, from a privacy point of view, we want that a user can only see the locations of those who are added in their friend list. We can't use the FB friend lists the users might not want to share their location with everyone on their FB friend list.

So, we need the following functionalities:

1. Authenticate user
2. Send friend request to others using the app
3. Display locations and profiles of only friends on app startup

Obviously, the backend will fetch the friend lists and the supporting data and we have a backend server already setup which is collecting the WiFi data. Something like [Elgg](http://elgg.org/) looked interesting but I don't know how to integrate it into Android. Something like what Whatsapp is using. XMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to integrate with Elgg, have a look at it's web services API: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Web_Services

You can use existing plugins to implement part of the logic on the backend side: https://github.com/Tachyon/Elgg-Web-Services

For more detailed support, seek help at [Elgg community discussion forums](http://community.elgg.org)